# Dot product of vectors containing only one element

Tags: linear-algebra

First of all, sorry if this sounds too basic: I beg your pardon, I'm not a math expert.

Apart from its concrete usefulness, is it theoretically possible to have a dot product with 2 vectors containing only 1 element?

Edit: Thanks anybody for patiently answering my question  :-)

Comment: What do you mean by a vector containing one element?

Comment: @Riquelme: v1=(1) and v2=(1), instead of, for example, v1=(1,2,3) and v2=(1,3,4)

Comment: The same rule goes-- multiply corresponding components and add those products. Only this time there's only one product to add so don't need the "add" portion.

Comment: @Arthur: basically, yes. I wanted to know if the theory requires at least two elements OR there can be 1 element. I'm simply building a programming function and I wondered if I should create an Exception for users inserting an array with less than 2 elements

Comment: @coffeemath: thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the standard dot product between vectors with three components:
$$
(1, 2, 3)\cdot (2, 3, 4) = 1\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 3 + 3\cdot 4
$$
Now consider the standard dot product between vectors with two components:
$$
(1, 2)\cdot (2, 3) = 1\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 3
$$
What would be the most natural way of extending this to vectors with only one component?

What you want is the regular multiplication of numbers, the way you learned in elementary school.

Comment: I wanted to know if the theory requires at least two elements OR there can be 1 element. I'm simply building a programming function and I wondered if I should create an Exception for users inserting an array with less than 2 elements

Comment: No, you do not as it does not contradict any definition

Comment: @Rice4000: ok, so the only thing to test is the empty vector (or vectors with different lengths or vectors not containing numbers). Thanks

Comment: @3rd If you read any _abstract_ definition of the dot product (i.e. any definition which is a list of properties like commutativity and linearity rather than a formula), you can check that regular multiplication does indeed satisfy them. Maybe you would have to search for "inner product" to actually get such a definition from the internet, thoguh.

Comment: @Arthur: thanks for the tip  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's possible. I do not know how relevant it is, but by pure computation you would have the following

Let $u = (u_1), \ v = (v_1) \in \mathbb{R}^1$
\begin{align*}
u \cdot v = \sum_{i=1}^1 u_i v_i = u_1 \cdot v_1 
\end{align*}
And hence this results in the normal multiplication we're familiar with in $\mathbb{R}^1$ (the real numbers).

Comment: Thanks! It is actually very relevant. It is the right answer I was looking for. This is the case when you can change the inner product to a simple multiplication!

Answer (score 1):

The one-dimensional vector space $\Bbb R^1$ is equipped with a standard dot product (or scalar product) - the normal multiplication.